# I am getting duplicate values on Postgres left join query

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I am getting duplicate values for user roles and teams, a user can have multiple roles, but I am getting duplicates: such:

```
  "roles": [
        {
            "role_id": 1,
            "role_name": "Admin"
        },
        {
            "role_id": 1,
            "role_name": "Admin"
        },
        {
            "role_id": 2,
            "role_name": "Moderator"
        },
        {
            "role_id": 2,
            "role_name": "Moderator"
        }
    ],
```

My query:

```
with aggs as (
  select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
         jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(r)) as roles,
         jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(t)) as teams,
         jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(s)) as something_else
    from users u
         left join user_role ur on ur.user_id = u.user_id
         left join roles r on r.role_id = ur.role_id
         left join user_team ut on ut.user_id = u.user_id
         left join teams t on t.team_id = ut.team_id
         left join user_something_else us on us.user_id = u.user_id
         left join something_else s on s.something_else_id = us.something_else_id
   group by u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
)
select to_jsonb(aggs)
  from aggs
 where user_id = 1;
```

tables example

```
create table users (
  user_id serial primary key,
  first_name text not null,
  last_name text not null,
  -- other columns here
);

create table roles (
  role_id serial primary key,
  role_name text not null unique,
  -- other columns here
);

create table user_role (
  id serial primary key,
  user_id int not null references users(user_id),
  role_id int not null references roles(role_id),
  unique(user_id, role_id)
);
```

the user_role table doesn't contain duplicates. But the query is returning duplicates.

How can I elemnate duplicates? I tried DISTNICT on u.user_id but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Did you make sure that `user_something_else.user_id` and `(user_team.user_id, user_team.team_id)` are unique? And btw no need to `group by` u.first_name and u.last_name since u.user_id is primary key.

Comment: @stefanov.sm yes they are all unique

Comment: Something is wrong with tables & data. How come that there are `"role_id": 1, "role_name": "Moderator"` and `"role_id": 1, "role_name": "Admin"` if role_id is primary key?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm sorry, my mistake. this is dummy data, I changed it